# How to write mock for HttpServletRequest re

Tags: spring-test

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<String> createEntity(HttpServletRequest request,
                                       @RequestBody(required = false) String payload) {
    return EntryControllerFunctions.createEntry(entityService, request, payload, 
                                                 AppConstants.ENTITY_CREATE_PAYLOAD,
                                                  AppConstants.ENTITES_URL, logger);
}
```

**how to write mock unit for HttpServletReqeust in this code**

Comment: Are you aware of `MockHttpServletRequest` -- https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mock/web/MockHttpServletRequest.html?

Comment: i want to know how to write unit test case for this code